# PromQL avg_over_time for non-zero values

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to get avg_over_time value from gauge metric, but I would want average only from the non-zero values of the metric (or values higher than zero, to be exact).

**Example:**

```
avg_over_time(foo[2d] > 0)
```

But I alwas get parse error:
`binary expression must contain only scalar and instant vector types`

I tried setting up recording rule

```
expr: foo > 0
```

But unfortunately with the same result.

*Is this possible in PromQL?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [sub-query](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) with Prometheus version above 2.7:

```
avg_over_time((foo > 0)[2d:])
```

Comment: what is the difference between [2d] and [2d:] ?
aren't they both same?

Comment: That the way subqueries are noted.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to use Prometheus subquery such as `avg_over_time((foo > 0)[2d:])` as Michael already mentioned, the proposed query may either miss certain data points or double-count certain datapoints depending on the `resolution` value after the colon in square brackets. For example, `avg_over_time((foo > 0)[2d:1h])` would take into account only a single raw data point per each hour when calculating `avg_over_time`, while `avg_over_time((foo>0)[2d:1s])` would count the same raw datapoints multiple times if scrape interval for `foo` exceeds `1s`. By default the `resolution` value [equals to `step` value](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/#subqueries) passed in the query to [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries), so the end result of the query may be quite different depending on the `step` query arg passed to `/api/v1/query_range`.

If you need to calculate the exact share of raw datapoints exceeding the given `threshold` independently of `step` query arg, then take a look at `share_gt_over_time(foo[2d], threshold)` function from [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html). This function may be useful for calculating SLO/SLI over uptime and/or latencies.